# Setting alias to use Macvim in terminal instead of standard Vim

Tags: bash, terminal, vim, alias, macvim

I want to use MacVim console app instead of a standard vim.
In order to accomplish that I try to set alias:

`alias vim="/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-119_1/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim"`
But for some reasons `alias` command doesn't work and each time I execute `which vim` it doesn't change and always shows `'/usr/local/bin/vim'` as a path. What's the matter?

Installing Macvim by 
`brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim`
doesn't work for me as it also requires to install GUI version of XCode that is too heavy (~5Gb)

Comment: Just a note. MacVim comes with a bash script `mvim`. So, you start MacVim using `mvim file`.

Comment: @jm666 correct, if you want to launch GUI version you start `mvim`, but MacVim also has console version that lies in MacVim folder according to the path I specified

Answer (score 1):

The `mvim` is universal starting (bash) script for the `MacVim`. It works based on his own name, e.g if it's name starts with `m` or `g` will start the GUI version, otherwise the console version.

You can see this in the `mvim` source:

```
case "$name" in m*|g*|rm*|rg*) gui=true ;; esac
```

Any other name will start the *console version*. So, it is enough to create an hard-link with the original `mvim`. For example, if your `mvim` is in the `/usr/local/bin/mvim` then

```
sudo ln /usr/local/bin/mvim /usr/local/bin/tvim
```

will create the `tvim` and the `tvim` command will start the console version of the `MacVim`. Of course, you can also create the link to `vim` like

```
sudo ln /usr/local/bin/mvim /usr/local/bin/vim
```

just must ensure that the `/usr/local/bin` is *before* the `/usr/bin` in the your `$PATH`.

### Now to your question:

Shadowing commands with aliases doesn't is the best practice. Anyway, it works. So, your

```
alias vim="/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-119_1/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim"
```

**will start** the MacVim's vim. The `which` command *doesn't* shows aliases. You can test it yourself, type directly into terminal:

```
alias bubu=/bin/date
```

the `which bubu` will show nothing, but if you run the `bubu` command you will get the date.

You can check which command will run using the `type`. E.g.

```
type bubu
#bubu is alias /bin/date
```

similarly

```
type vim
#will show the /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-119_1/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
```

Also, you can check the current variables directly from your running `vim`, just use the `:set runtimepath` or `:set helpfile` will show for the default `/usr/bin/vim` something like:

```
... /usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after
```

but for your MacVim (in console mode) will show like:

```
... /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-119_1/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimfiles
```

So, finally:

- your alias probably works, just the `which` doesn't shows it
- you can use the provided `mvim` just hardlink it to another name